# Drag and Drop to wrapped flex items using react

Tags: reactjs, drag-and-drop, draggable, react-beautiful-dnd, react-grid-layout

I have to create a drag and drop functionalities to some dynamically created list items just like the image below:[image]

Here the, items will be displayed by using flex and items will be wrapped by flex-wrap: wrap so that it adjust the items into multi lines. I need to add the drag and drop functionalities here so that I can move the individual items anywhere within the lists.
I have found some libraries like: react-beautiful-dnd but it doesn't allow handling the drag and drop to multiple lines.Does anybody have some good recommendations, how to acheive this or which library I should use. Thanks in advance.